# Qual a melhor forma de fazer uma requisição AJAX no WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, cliente-servidor, lado-do-cliente

Quando eu faço uma requisição AJAX no WordPress eu faço de duas formas, mas gostaria de saber qual a melhor.

As duas que eu conheço é:

1º) Você coloca sua função no functions, por ex:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my-function','my_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_busca-my-function','my_function');
function my_function(){
  //code
}
```

2ª) Você cria um arquivo, chama nele as funções do Wordpress pelo wp-blog-header e faz o retorno.

Então, tem mais alguma forma? Qual seria a melhor? Estou desenvolvendo um portal de notícias, e a ideia é ter uma linha do tempo como a do Stack Overflow, onde a cada notícia nova o cliente é notificado para atualizar.

Answer (score 2):

Usando a segunda forma você vai carregar o WordPress duas vezes: uma no *load* normal da página e a segunda ao incluir o `wp-blog-header.php` ou `wp-load.php`. Tem um post no *Crappy Code* dedicado a isso: [wp-load.php – I Will Find You!](http://crappycode.wordpress.com/2012/12/13/wp-load-php-i-will-find-you/)

O correto é a 1ª forma, chamando o AJAX através das *actions* `wp_ajax_*` (sendo o `nopriv` para usuários que não estão logados) e passando a URL do `wp-ajax.php` (e nonce de segurança) através do [`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script):

```
wp_enqueue_script( 
    'meu-ajax',       // handler
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/meu-ajax.js', // ou plugins_url( '/js/meu-ajax.js', __FILE__ )
    array( 'jquery' ) // dependencia
);
wp_localize_script( 
    'meu-ajax',       // handler
    'wp_ajax',        // objeto disponível em meu-ajax.js
    array( 
         'ajaxurl'   => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
         'ajaxnonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'ajax_post_validation' ) 
    ) 
);
```

<sup><sub>Exemplo de plugin completo: [How to Use AJAX in a WordPress Shortcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13614297/1287812)</sub></sup>

Comment: Quando eu usei no functions, ocorreu em alguns servidores de dá erro 404(not found) ou 505..Mas do nada voltava ao normal, já passou por isso?

Comment: Não, nunca vi... como é que você monta a URL do `admin-ajax.php`? . . . E, só lembrando, se a funcionalidade que vc implementa tem que sobreviver se vc mudar de theme, então deve-se usar um plugin em vez de colocar em `functions.php`.